# Path with params and php realpath

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, merge, parameters, realpath

During the merger of several css need convert relative paths to absolute.

One of the steps - get realpath.

There Bootstrap with its css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Result after ***realpath***:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    src: url("/somepath/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
    src: url("") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("/somepath/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/somepath/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("") format("svg");
}
```

For paths with params returned *false*.

How can get the realpath for path with params and **save params**?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean php's function "realpath" ?
If that's the case, it's not meant to be used on url, but on file system paths.

If you want to use absolute paths for your fonts, it should start with a "/".
ie : url("/css/fonts/glyphicons-whateveryoulike.ttf")

The "/" at the beginning will be the root of your web directory.

Comment: Steps of css-merge ~:  if _preg_math_all_(url) -> exclude _substr_(protocol and data:) -> realpath -> get webpath